# Script to run other scripts in sqldeveloper

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a number of scripts used to build a database.  These need to be executed in a certain order.  Is it possible to create a script to run other scripts in SQL Developer (1.5.3)?

I know I can do this with sqlplus, but I was hoping there's a similar ability I just don't know about.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The SQL*Plus synthax works (with `run script`):

```
@script arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

or

```
@"/path/to/directory/script" arg1 arg2 ... argn
```

Comment: That works - thanks.  Both answers seem to work - I'm not sure what the difference is between @ and @@ - but gave this one the check for mentioning the path, which is required if the script isn't in the default directory.

Comment: @subdir/script.sql looks for the file in a sub-directory under the current working directory whereas @@ssubdir/script.sql looks for the file in a subdirectory under the directory where the calling script is located.

Answer (score 12):

SqlDeveloper should be able to use the same syntax as SqlPlus, i.e.

```
@@ script1
@@ script2
@@ script3
```

This will execute `script1.sql`, `script2.sql` and `script3.sql` in order.