# Run SQL*Plus Script That Runs Other Script files

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Ok, so I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1367406/script-to-run-other-scripts-in-sqldeveloper) but I don't think the answer matches the question.  I believe the OP is asking how to create a SQL*Plus script that runs other SQL*Plus scripts but the chosen answer reveals how to run a SQL script in SQL*Plus.

I would like to know how to create a SQL*Plus script that, when run, executes other SQL*Plus scripts within the same directory.

Comment: Use either the `@` or the `@@` commands to run your script. [Reference here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a90842/ch13.htm). Share and enjoy.

Comment: What is an "SQL script", as distinct from an "SQL*Plus script"? The answer on that question shows how to run one script from another. Any of the scripts can contain SQL*Plus commands (`set` for example), not just SQL. I don't understand why you think this doesn't work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The given answer is correct.
Create a directory with two files:
control.sql
second.sql

make control.sql contain:

```
set serveroutput on

prompt "Start of control"
/

@second.sql
/

prompt "End of control"
/
```

make second.sql contain:

```
prompt "Start of Second"
/

prompt "End of Second"
/
```

Then run control.sql